# $H\le G$, $G$ topological group $H$ open $\Rightarrow H$ closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By definition if $G$ is a topological group then there exits $\nu:G\times G\rightarrow G$ defined by $(g,h)\mapsto gh^{-1}$ continous.

Then Let $H\le G$ be open. Clearly $H=H\cdot 1^{-1}=1\cdot H$.

Hence $\nu^{-1}(H)=\nu^{-1}(H\cdot 1^{-1})=(H,1)$ and $\nu^{-1}(H)=\nu^{-1}(1\cdot H)=(1,H)$ from which we would have $H=1$.

Where did I wrong? How can I prove that $H\le G$ open $\Rightarrow$ $H$ closed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The set equality $v^{-1}(H\cdot1^{-1})=H\times1$ is extremely untrue. For instance $(h,h^{-1})$ is in this preimage for nontrivial $h\in H$, but not in $H\times1$. Rhetorical question: what were you hoping to accomplish by looking at $v^{-1}(H)$? $H$ closed means its complement is open which means its complement is a union of open sets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $$H=G\setminus\bigcup_{x\in G\setminus H } xH .$$

Comment: In words: $H$ is the complement of a union of cosets of $H$.